# How to make copy of a treeview nodes to another treeview

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How do I take the data from one populated treeview and put it into another existing treeview.
All the nodes and children need to be copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TTreeNode` implements the `TPersistent.Assign()` method, so one option would be to write a recursive function that iterates the source TreeView adding-and-assigning nodes to the target TreeView. For example:

```
procedure CopyNodes(SrcTree, DstTree: TTreeView);
var
  DstNodes: TTreeNodes;
  SrcRootNode: TTreeNode;

  procedure DoCopyNodes(SrcNode, Relative: TTreeNode; AddMode: TNodeAttachMode);
  var
    DstNode: TTreeNode;
  begin
    while SrcNode <> nil do
    begin
      DstNode := DstNodes.AddNode(nil, Relative, '', nil, AddMode);
      try
        DstNode.Assign(SrcNode);
        DoCopyNodes(SrcNode.GetFirstChild, DstNode, naAddChild);
      except
        DstNode.Delete;
        raise;
      end;
      SrcNode := SrcNode.GetNextSibling;    
    end;
  end;

begin
  SrcRootNode := SrcTree.Items.GetFirstNode;
  if SrcRootNode <> nil then
  begin
    DstNodes := DstTree.Items;
    DstNodes.BeginUpdate;
    try
      DoCopyNodes(SrcRootNode, nil, naAdd);
    finally
      DstNodes.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

```
CopyNodes(TreeView1, TreeView2);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use a stream to save and load tree content. I don't have a running environment right now to test an example but, your code could looks like :

```
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Tree1.SaveToStream(MS);
    MS.Position := 0;
    Tree2.LoadFromStream(MS);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I added the required `MS.Position := 0;`

Comment: When I a tried without the position nothing copied over.  When I added the position all I get is the first node, no childs or any other nodes.  Any Idea ?

Comment: I have no idea. It works 100 % for me. Perhaps it could help if you would edit your question and add your code as well as an image of your tree you tested with, fully expanded. Or if it is very large, create a small test case with a few levels of subtrees.